# Assuming no duplicates, do Sets always outperform Linked Lists?

Tags: javascript, linked-list, set, time-complexity

Recently I have been looking into JavaScript Sets and it seems to me that as long as you are not dealing with duplicate data, they match or outperform Linked Lists in every scenario. Is this fair, or is there a scenario in which Linked Lists are superior?

```
const set = new Set();
set.add(someValue)            // O(1) time
set.delete(someValue)         // O(1) time
set.has(someValue)            // O(1) time

const ll = new LinkedList();
ll.append(someValue)          // O(1) time
ll.deleteHead()               // O(1) time

// Remove item from anywhere inside Linked List
ll.delete(someValue)          // O(n) time
ll.contains(someValue)        // O(n) time
```

Comment: `LinkedList` is not a built-in type in JavaScript.

Comment: Yes. But assuming I have implemented `LinkedList` would my assumptions hold?

Comment: Yes. Sets are very efficient ways to store unique values.

Comment: In JavaScript LinkedList never has an advantage; it serves as an academic tool only. In JavaScript a Set or an Array will always outperform a LinkedList implementation. Prove me wrong ;-)

Comment: Also, better time complexity doesn't mean better performance. Time complexity only describes rate of growth of an algorithm, not performance on all workloads. If you have small values of `n`, O(1) is often slower than O(n), for example `new Set(arr).has(foo)` vs `arr.includes(foo)` when `arr.length` is, say, 10. Anyway, this question doesn't make much sense because you're comparing an unoptimized user-implemented data structure with a highly-optimized builtin. Apples and oranges. The "no duplicate" constraint means you'd never want to use anything but a set since that's its entire purpose.

Comment: Be careful with absolute words like "always" in terms of performance, but here it pretty much trivially is "always" as trincot mentions. Linked lists truly are useless in JS and you will practically never outperform a builtin data structure that many smart people who wrote the engine (say, Google's V8) have worked hard for years to optimize.